# $\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\log k}{k^p}$ and $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{k^{\log k}}$ both converge

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Show that each of the following series converges

1) $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{\log k}{k^p}$, $p > 1$.

2) $\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^\infty \dfrac{1}{k^{\log k}}$.

Can anyone please help me start this problems.
I think I can use the comparison theorem. Thank you.

Comment: You can use the [integral test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence)

Comment: For the second one, notice that $\log k>1$ for $k\geq 3$.

Comment: for both of them?

Comment: The first series is the derivative of the [Riemann $\zeta$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** $$\int_{3}^\infty \frac{\log x}{x^p}dx=\int_{\log 3}^\infty e^{-(p-1)z}z dz<\frac{1}{(p-1)^2}\\
\int_{1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{x^{\log x}}dx=\int_{0}^{\infty}ze^{-z^2}dz=\frac{1}{2}$$

Comment: For integral test to be valid the function has to be non negative and decreasing on some $[N,\infty)$. since $\log n\ge 0$ for $n\ge 3$, I used $3$. And you can always change from base $10$ to base $e$ by a constant multiplication right?

Answer (score 2):

The [Cauchy Condensation Test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) works well in these kinds of problems:
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\log(k)}{k^p}\iff\sum_{k=1}^\infty\dfrac{k\log(2)2^k}{2^{kp}}
$$
and
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{k^{\log(k)}}\iff\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2^k}{2^{k^2\log(2)}}
$$